# Exception 0xC0000409 (stack buffer overflow) when using dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, dynamic-cast

I'm experiencing a crash when trying to `dynamic_pointer_cast` a shared point of type `A` to type `B`.
Type `B` is not related to type `A` and I'd expect an empty `shared_ptr` but instead, the exception above is raised.
Is there any scenario where it isn't safe to use `dynamic_pointer_cast`?

Exception raised here:

[image]

Using MSVC 14.16.27023

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.  I cannot reproduce the problem.  Is the `dynamic_pointer_cast` conversion you're using abide by the `dynamic_cast` restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::dynamic_pointer_cast` requires that the conversion of `U*` (source) to `T*` (destination) is well formed.  If it isn't then you have undefined behavior.  If you want to get a null pointer like you would from `dynamic_cast` then you are going to have to write your own version that will do this.

Another option is test the result of

```
dynamic_cast<decltype(destination_ptr.get())>(source_ptr.get())
```

And if that succeeds then call `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` else return a null pointer.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. can you please point me to the definition of "well formed cast" so I'll be able to verify this relationship for `A` & `B`?

Comment: @SagiLow In this case well formed means that if you did a dynamic cast of the underlying pointer types you would get a good cast (not a null pointer as lond as the source is not a null pointer).  So, if you have `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<std::shared_ptr<A>>(object_of_shared_ptr_B)` then you need `dynamic_cast<A*>(object_of_pointer_to_B)` to be valid.